# Error converting from String to int to Vaadin

Tags: java, spring, string, int, vaadin

I'm trying to convert a String to int in Vaadin. Here is the code:

```
TextField name = new TextField();
int num;
num = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(name.getValue()));
Paragraph greeting = new Paragraph("");
Button button = new Button("Result", event -> {
    greeting.setText(" " + num * 500);
});
add(name, button, greeting);
```

And here is the error:

```
There was an exception while trying to navigate to '' with the exception message 'Error creating bean with name 'com.gmail.ilim.MainView': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.gmail.ilim.MainView]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""'
```

Comment: What is the expected result when u insert `""` into `Integer.parseInt` function? Not sure what you wanted to do but you're trying to parse an empty String which causes the `NumberFormatException`

Comment: In the end of a message there is a `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""` which means it cannot parse empty string as int. Here `name = new TextField();` you create TextField with empty initial value, and you use it as input in the next line, you can't expect a value there.

Comment: It seems like you want this `int num = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(name.getValue()));` to be inside of `event->{}`, so you enter value in name, press the button, and get num*500 in greeting, am I right?

Comment: Btw. calling `String.valueOf(name.getValue())` is pointless. `name.getValue()` already returns a String so parsing String out of it does nothing.

Comment: besides doing what yuri said, you must also implement exception handling, aka try-catch around the `Integer.parseInt(..)` line which should be inside the button click event.

Comment: Yes you are right. When you click a button, the result should appear, multiply it by 500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was said in the comments:

1) parse the input value only within the button's clicklistener, not directly inside the constructor of the view (at that point, the `TextField` will always have empty value)

2) catch the NumberFormatException. Even when having point 1 taken care of, the user can always type in non-numeric stuff which will not be parseable to `Integer`

```
TextField name = new TextField();
Paragraph greeting = new Paragraph("");
Button button = new Button("Result", event -> {
    int num;
    try {
        num = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(name.getValue()));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        num = 0; // your default value
        // you should also let the user know he didnt enter a valid number
        Notification.show("Please enter a valid number");
    }
    greeting.setText(" " + num * 500);
});
add(name, button, greeting);
```

Another possibility is to directly use a `IntegerField` instead of `TextField`. This is only available for Vaadin 14.1.x

Yet another possibility that comes into my mind is using a Binder - when binding the textField you could add a `StringToIntegerConverter`. This is going to be a little more complicated and I wouldn't go that route just for this.

Answer (score 1):

As the other people in comments said, one solution would be to catch the Exception so:

```
try {
  num = Integer.parseInt(name.getValue());
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
  num = 1; // your default value
}
...
```